# NGINX proxy_pass without changing URL

Tags: proxy, nginx, url, reverse-proxy

### My Goal

My goal is to redirect to a different web page without changing the URL in the address bar. So for example I want to redirect from `https://my.site.com/path` to `https://external.com/other`, but only the content of the page should change, not the URL.

### Current configuration

This is what I have tried. I thought, that `proxy_redirect` might be a good idea, so I based the configuration on the [NGINX docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect). But while this does load the content of `https://external.com/other`, the URL in the address bar changes to `https://my.site.com/other`. The domain name stays the same, but the path changes.

```
location = /path {
    proxy_pass https://external.com/other;
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```